# topological sort on boost graph for vertices that are connected through a given vertex only

Tags: boost-graph

I have a large graph which represents a set of dependencies.

- A -->B
- A -->C
- B -->F
- C -->G
- D -->E
- E -->L
- F -->H
- F -->I
- H -->K
- J -->K

Given B as a starting node, result needs to be : B F I H K

I do not need any other nodes since they cannot be reached from B.

A user can specify a node and I need to collect all the paths and the nodes in those paths and print the topological sort of those nodes.

Currently I am implementing this by

1. Create a new graph
2. Extract all the outgoing edges from the given node.
3. Add those edges in a graph. From those edges, get the nodes and also add them to the new graph.
4. For each node in step 3, repeat (2) and (3)
5. On that new graph, perform a topological sort and get the order of the nodes

   Is there any other better way to do this or known algorithm for finding the topological sort of a subset of nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the depth_first_visit() function, and the Visitor Pattern provided by boost.  The Visitor Pattern allows you to inspect vertices and edges as the tree is searched.  The depth_first_visit() function allows you to start a DFS search starting at a specific vertex.